# XSL - Exclude access to ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET

Tags: java, sonarqube, xslt-2.0, sax

I'm looking for informations and a solution regarding an issue that I have with my implementation of SAXParser to perform XSL Transformation.

In order to improve the quality of our project, the sonarqube sensitivity has been rised. Then a new error appearred for my implementation.

[image: Here the sonarqube issue]

Sonarqube is asking me to set properties to empty value in order to exclude the possibilities of an attack based on those values.

Problem, if I can set the property for ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD and ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA to empty correctly, the property ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET seems to not be a valid property for SAXParser. And without it set correctly, sonarqube doesn't remove the blocker error as it seems mandatory for XSL Transformation.

```
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        saxParser.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, ""); // Work
        saxParser.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, ""); // Work
        saxParser.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, ""); // Doesn't work and throw org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException
```

What should I do ?

I'm under Saxon-HE:9.8.0-8

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure the problem is related to Saxon 9, an XSLT 3 processor? Or is it simply a problem of the SAXParser that is part of the JAXP JRE API? Which version of Java is that?

Comment: Yeah it should be related to Java I think as SAXParser is coming from javax library. But I don't know why sonarqube refuse to see that all available property has been set to be protected